# The limit of the improper integral $\lim_{r\to 0} \int_{0}^{r} \log(1-e^{ix})dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, limits

I wonder how to rigorously show

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \int_{0}^{r} \log(1-e^{ix})dx=0$$

(let me know if it is not zero or the limit does not exist)

By the "intemediate value theorem" of  integrals, we know
$ \int_{s}^{r} \log(1-e^{ix})dx$ can be bounded by $(r-s)|\log(1-e^{ix_s})|$ for some $x_s\in [s,r]$. But the hard part is that $x_s$ can go to zero much faster when $s$ tends to 0. So I don't know how to deal with this.

Comment: $|\log(1-e^{ix})|= |\log \sin x/2|+O(1)=|\log x|+ O(1), \epsilon>x >0$ and $|\log x|=-\log x$ is integrable at zero as one can see by looking at the antiderivative

Answer (score 1):

since we are talking about $r$ being "small" we can also see $x$ as small, and so we can make the approximation:
$$1-e^{ix}=(1-\cos(x))-i\sin(x)\approx-ix$$
so we can redefine our integral as:
$$I(r)=\int_0^r\log(-ix)dx=\int_0^r\left[\log(-i)+\log(x)\right]dx=\log(-i)r+r(\ln r-1)$$
and now take the limit as $r\to0$, obviously the first term vanishes and it can be shown using L'Hopital that the second term $\to0$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{r \to 0}
\int_{0}^{r}\ln\pars{1 - \expo{\ic x}}\,\dd x}:
\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\lim_{r \to 0}\,
\int_{0}^{r}\ln\pars{1 - \expo{\ic x}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{r \to 0}\,
\int_{1}^{\exp\pars{\ic r}}\ln\pars{1 - z}\,
{\dd z \over \ic z}
\\[5mm] = &\
\ic\,\lim_{r \to 0}\,
\int_{1}^{\exp\pars{\ic r}}
\on{Li}_{2}'\pars{z}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\ic\,\lim_{r \to 0}\bracks{\on{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{\ic r}} -
\on{Li}_{2}\pars{1}} = \bbx{\large 0} \\ &
\end{align}

$\ds{\on{Li}_{s}}$ is the
[Polylogarithm Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

In the above evaluation, the $\ds{\ln}$-branch cut is taken along $\ds{\pars{1,\infty}}$ which coincides with the Polylogarithm branch-cut.